# What does babelRelayPlugin, transform-runtime, passPerPreset do? (babel+webpack configuration)

Tags: webpack, babeljs, relayjs

I am new in Relay and I am looking at its' babel+webpack configuration and somehow I need help in understanding its' .babelrc - this is the code:

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "plugins": [
        "./build/babelRelayPlugin"
      ]
    },
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

This is the code on babelRelayplugin.js, this is short but I need help understanding this:

```
const getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
const schema = require('../data/schema.json');

module.exports = getBabelRelayPlugin(schema.data);
```

I understand   "react", "es2015", "stage-0" on presets, babel transform the code to js that browser understand.I have done my search and this is the information I have, which I don't understand and have confusion:

- babelRelayPlugin - Relay uses a babel plugin to convert from Relay.QL
  string templates to JavaScript code that describes each query and
  includes data from the GraphQL schema.
- passPerPreset:true -  will modify how babel traverses through
  plugins. Instead of a single traversal in which all plugins/presets
  are merged together, each preset will get their own traversal.(what does it mean?)
- "plugins": ["transform-runtime"] - all of the helpers will reference
  the module babel-runtime to avoid duplication across your compiled
  output. The runtime will be compiled into your build

Would really appreciate if someone help me understand what these are and what they do.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you read [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/935) of Relay repository, and the links contained in it.